# Why don't I get a error logs for 500 Interal Errors in my logs directory in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a 2 deployed `ASP.NET Core RC1 web application` based off the default asp.net core template.

Both work correctly.

However I touched the web.config of one as I wanted to restart the application and then I got the following error.

> :(  Oops.
>   500 Internal Server Error
>   An error occurred while starting the application.

How do I troubleshoot why the application cannot start up? I reaplced it with the original web.config but I still get the error when I access the site URL.

I have 3 directories
-approot
-wwwroot
-logs

Why is the logs directory empty when I get the error

I am using the default logging that was in an asp.net template

my appsettings.json

```
     "Logging": {
        "IncludeScopes": false,
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Verbose",
          "System": "Information",
          "Microsoft": "Information"
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the standard ASP.NET Core template to write log files the only thing that you need to change is the `web.config`. This is assuming you haven't changed any else different in the default template code.

Change `stdoutLogEnabled` from `false` to `true`

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
<httpPlatform  processPath="..\approot\web.cmd" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="..\logs\stdout.log" startupTimeLimit="3600"></httpPlatform>
</system.webServer>
```